# Blender 3D Game Projects?

Tags: game-engine

I am just beginning learning to use Blender and I was wondering if some of you have some sample game projects. Or if you know any good book, forum or videos tutorials for the last version of Blender (2.72). Thanks.

Comment: http://www.yofrankie.org/download/

Comment: See http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?256650-Quality-Blender-Games-LINKS for a comprehensive list; we should add this to the resources question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: Check this list of Blender games on [Blender-Artist](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?256650-Quality-Blender-Games-LINKS)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for links to tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that before you learn to use the blender game engine, you learn to use the normal blender engine so you can get the hang of the basics and it hugely minimizes some of avoidable mistakes - and if my experience was anything to go by, you'll make a ton.

I would recommend that you mess around with it, try to set yourself basic project and you'll slowly learn how to do new things and old things more efficiently.

Here are a few websites I would recommend:

- https://www.youtube.com/user/CGAstym
- https://www.youtube.com/user/GlebAlexandrov
- http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Game_Engine/Tutorials_index.html
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9057AB8E3C66AE80 and [archived](https://cgcookie.com/archive/blender-basics-introduction-for-beginners/)